# Telling if a word is a verb in the imperative mood

Tags: parts-of-speech, syntactic-analysis, imperatives

I'm working on a static analysis tool for the documentation in the Python programming  language (PEP257). For this, I need to check if the first word in a documentation string is a verb in the imperative mood.

Our current check is that the word should not end with an "s", except if it ends with a double "s".
So "Pass" is okay, but "Passes" is not.
The problem with the current test is that it has false negatives, e.g., "Focus".

Is there a way to check for this? Assuming that the word is already a verb is fine. If the check can sometimes fail, I rather it failed on passing the test (concluding that a verb is in the imperative mood) than vice-versa.

Comment: You cannot check this automatically. It must be done manually. There's no non-manual way that would check an imperative, but not a past tense, gerund, present tense (outside the third singular), subjunctive, or infinitive. That's why all the big text corpora are manually tagged.

Comment: Why not look at the exclamation mark at the end?

Comment: @Affable Geek: Remember that commands [don't](http://www.english-grammar-revolution.com/imperative-sentence.html) have to end in exclamation points.

Comment: And imperatives express not only direct commands, but also prohibitions and requests. In many circumstances, using the imperative mood may sound blunt or even rude, so it is often used with care. Examples: "Paul, do your homework now". "Do not clean soot off the window." "Turn your phones off, please." "Run down to the shop, will you, Peter." An imperative is used to tell someone to do something [/refrain from doing something] without argument. [Wikipedia; augmented]

Comment: A fundamental problem with your approach (already alluded to by JBJ and EA above) is that it doesn't take account of the many ways an imperative can be expressed. Your approach would fail to identify such cases as the following: 1) Please [do X]; 2) It is highly desirable [to do X]; 3) [Doing X] is recommended; 4) IF statements, e.g. "If X is the case, then [do Y]"; 5) Depending on the outcome of X, it may be necessary to [do Y]. And so on. The upshot, as JBJ has concluded, is that a manual analysis will always be required (though a few verb forms can be automatically excluded first).

Comment: There is no "imperative mood" in English. There are imperative uses of infinitive verb forms (_Be kind, Get out of here, Look at that_), but they can only be distinguished in context, because there's nothing grammatical about them that distinguishes them from other infinitives. So you'd have to do a full pragmatic parse and then choose the ones you thought were true imperatives. This would leave out, for instance, constructions like _Buy ten and save!_, [which can be shown not to be imperative constructions](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/conics.pdf).

Comment: @JohnLawler First and least, although modern dependency or constituency parsers can be run in a way to assign POS tags as they run, I don’t recall any that include the info the OP is looking for—but even if they do, it’s always just a guess with some correctness confidence less than 1. Most importantly, thanks very much for that paper reference, as I have always been uncomfortable with calling those forms “imperatives” when they feel more like “masked conditionals” or non-participial “concessives” to me. Did Old English use present subjunctive inflections there, or morphological infinitives?

Answer (score 4):

To determine if a verb is a command just from its spelling seems problematic.  Start with the basic rule: "In English, the imperative is formed using the bare infinitive form of the verb. This is usually also the same as the second-person present indicative form...." (from Wikipedia) So it seems what you're really trying to check is whether the verb that starts the sentence is in the present tense, second person. Since you're only concerned with false negatives, then you need to spot verbs ending in "s" that should be exceptions to your first rule (can't end in "s").  Someone suggested you remove the "s" and analyze what you get.  Instead, I would recommend that you add "es" and see if you still have a verb.  If so, it has a high probability that the original is something you want. So if you encounter "guess", then check "guesses" (still a verb).  If you encounter "guesses", check "guesseses" (not a verb).

Comment: Just adding 'es' is a terrible idea; Activate, Add, Copy, Extract, Get, Move all fail that test.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether your task is feasible, but it would help to make the test look at whether the verb ends with an inflection (rather than whether it ends with "s").  One property of English inflections is that when you remove them, you get a word that is the base form.  So your example "focus" would clearly not pass this test, since "focu" is not a verb.